# class instance pointers or function pointers?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management

This is a c++ question. We would like to have 2 utility functions that have different implementations depending on a certain parameter, during runtime it is determined which implementation should be called based on this parameter, what design could be best in terms of memory usage and performance? We are thinking of two approaches but we can’t determine the improvement gained in either: 
-   Defining an interface for these 2 utility functions and having multiple classes extending them, then we create a map with instances of these class implementations (eager initialising)
-   define all these functions in one class as static functions and invoke them using function pointers

Comment: This sounds like a basic interface use case. Create a base interface with the function needed and then create two classes implementing the function.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to parse, but it seems what you need is inheritance and virtual methods...

Comment: There are actually (at least) 4 ways of achieving this: simple switch/case based on the parameter, function pointer indexed by the parameter (check for valid parameter), polymorphic class gotten from a factory method via switch/case or polymorphic class gotten from a factory using a map.  If performance really matters, there are probably cases where the first approach is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual inheritance is usually realized using function pointers, so both of your ideas boil down to the same thing (from compiler point of view).

On a second thought, you are considering performance of a something as basic as function call. Are you 100% sure you're optimizing the part that is the bottleneck? It's extremely easy to get sidetracked when optimizing, and spend days on something which has 0 or 1% impact on performance. So stick to the golden rule: prove which part really slows you down. If you write tests for it, it'll be easy to test both solutions and get the results which one is faster.